# Nifi update value in column in condition to another column

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I want to update a csvflowfile. I tried update record but I didn't get any progress.
I want to set two different outcomes in col1 depending of what is in col2

I want to update a specific column under the following condition.

```
col a        | col b
not inside   | 
something in | has some values
```

So I want to write in col a  "not inside" when col b is empty,
when colb has values in it, col a has to be "something in".

Comment: Use a `QueryRecord` processor